# NSCollectionView - How to make Finder's Icon View?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to implement something similar to Finder's Icon View - where the icons can be freely located by drag and drop (no rows and columns arrangement). Is it possible to make it with NSCollectionView?

[Finder's Icon View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9ewY.png)

Is it possible to somehow turn off NSCollectionView auto-arrangement? Or create NSCollectionViewLayout which supports this?

Comment: Hint: [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace].

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get it

Comment: I would recommend to use NSCollectionView to implement a Finder like icon view but you will have to subclass NSCollectionViewLayout to get your own custom  layout. NSCollectionViewFlowLayout or NSCollectionViewGridLayout will not handle this for you.

Comment: I think so. Is there any example of the layout subclass which supports the free icons arrangement?

Comment: For a complete custom layout like the one you're describing, you'll need your own layout subclass. This isn't too hard to do and the process is described a fair amount here. Essentially you need to override a few methods, the `layoutAttributesFor` methods are what determine where your elements will be placed and you can manually assign the location for each attribute you return for a given item. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewlayout